# Getting exit code from Java back to PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to get the exit code from a Java method back to PL/SQL. It appears that there is always an exception. How can I find out what the exceptio
n was. I am running on 12c.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE JAVA SOURCE NAMED UTLCMD AS
  2  import java.lang.Runtime;
  3  public class UTLCMD
  4  {
  5      public static int execute(String command)
  6      {
  7          int exitCode = 0;
  8
  9          try
 10          {
 11              Runtime rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
 12              Process proc = rt.exec(command);
 13              exitCode = proc.waitFor();
 14          }
 15          catch(Exception e)
 16          {
 17              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 18              exitCode = 12;
 19          }
 20
 21          return exitCode;
 22      }
 23  }
 24  /

Java created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JavaRunShellCommand(
  2      command IN VARCHAR2)
  3      RETURN NUMBER
  4  AS LANGUAGE JAVA
  5      NAME 'UTLCMD.execute(java.lang.String) return oracle.sql.NUMBER';
  6  /

Function created.
```

Here are the results from trying to call the method.

```
SQL> VARIABLE n NUMBER;
SQL> CALL JavaRunShellCommand('cmd.exe /C CALL C:\Users\pwatson\src\java\my.bat') INTO :n;

Call completed.

SQL> PRINT n

         N
----------
        12

SQL> CALL JavaRunShellCommand('cmd.exe /C EXIT /B 3') INTO :n;

Call completed.

SQL> PRINT n

         N
----------
        12

SQL> SELECT JavaRunShellCommand('cmd.exe /C CALL C:\Users\pwatson\src\java\my.bat') AS R FROM DUAL;

         R
----------
        12

SQL> SELECT JavaRunShellCommand('cmd.exe /C EXIT /B 3') AS R FROM DUAL;

         R
----------
        12
```

Comment: Have you run `dbms_java.grant_permission` for `cmd.exe`? Your're writing the error to the console, so you need to check your trace files to find it. Why are you catching exceptions though, it might be simpler to let them bubble up to your session.

Comment: Change the return type to a  string, and return the exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that oracle.exe is running as the machine\oracle user and did not have permission in my directory. When I moved everything to C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN, it started working as expected. The solution came from the Oracle Community site. https://community.oracle.com/thread/3669270

Many thanks to everyone who had suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an exception since you're getting 12 back, but you are trapping all exceptions and only displaying them with `System.out.println()`, and Java console output goes into a trace file - you (or your DBA) will need to find the right file and extract the actual fault.

It would be simpler to let the exception be thrown:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE JAVA SOURCE NAMED UTLCMD AS
import java.lang.Runtime;
public class UTLCMD
{
    public static int execute(String command)
    throws java.lang.InterruptedException, java.io.IOException
    {
        int exitCode = 0;
        Runtime rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(command);
        exitCode = proc.waitFor();
        return exitCode;
    }
}
/
```

If I run that with a command (Unix-y in my case) then I see the real problem:

```
exec :n := JavaRunShellCommand('/bin/ls /tmp');

ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.security.AccessControlException: the Permission (java.io.FilePermission /bin/ls execute) has not been granted to STACKOVERFLOW. The PL/SQL to grant this is dbms_java.grant_permission( 'STACKOVERFLOW', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '/bin/ls', 'execute' )
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.JAVARUNSHELLCOMMAND", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 1
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.
```

Which is the same as I saw in the trace file when trying it your way, but rather easier to access.

If I fix my problem by issuing the `dbms_java.grant_permission()` call (as a DBA) as the error helpfully told me to, and reconnect, it now works:

```
exec :n := JavaRunShellCommand('/bin/ls /tmp');
anonymous block completed

print n
N
-
0
```

Of course you might well be getting a different exception, but you need to find out what it is before you can start tackling the real issue.

Comment: Oops! I spoke a bit soon. The my.bat script exits with an exit code of 7, but 1 is always returned. I granted 'execute' permission to '<<ALL FILES>>'.C:\Users\pwatson\src\java>type my.bat
@echo off
echo now
exit /b 7

Comment: It returns 1, not 0? Even with the `/c` switch? I might expect that from `cmd.exe` itself not erroring, but not with the switch. I think. Do you have to run `cmd.exe`, or can you just call `my.bat` directly in the exec call? (This isn't really my area... *8-)

Comment: Yes, I must run cmd.exe as it is the interpreter for the my.bat text. Windows does not have a shebang to specify the interpreter. It returns 1 whether or not 'CALL' is used. You have gotten this much further down the road, but I am going to uncheck the answer icon in hopes that someone might come through with the exit code.

Comment: @Paul - I vaguely thought you could exec bat files directly. Up to you of course, but I'd ask a new question just about that behaviour - with a single specific command you run and the bat file, and without the Oracle bits if you can get the same behaviour from running the same code from the shell. And maybe tagged with something DOS-y *8-)

Comment: If I run the Java code outside of Oracle, the correct exit code is returned. Is that what you were alluding to?